# Web Package: How to force MSBuild to use MSDeploy.IisApp instead of sitemanifest?

Tags: iis, msbuild, msdeploy

How do I force MSBuild to create a Web Package that uses the [iisApp Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd569054%28v%253dws.10%29) Application Path such as "Default Web Site/Catalog"?

My build process is creating a package that uses a directory path (C:\Agent\_work\28\s\Catalog).

I have tried to add the "/p:DeployAsIisApp=True" in my MSBuild command, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

If I set the virtual directory to my Visual Studio 2017 solution folder, then [Export a Package through IIS Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/export-a-package-through-iis-manager), the package is created the way I'm expecting.

I compared the archive.xml files between MSBuild and the IIS Export. Here is some partial output:

MSBuild:

```
<sitemanifest MSDeploy.ObjectResolver.createApp= ...>
  <iisApp path="C:\Agent\_work\28\s\Catalog ...>
  ...
</sitemanifest>
```

IIS Export:

```
<MSDeploy.IisApp MSDeploy.ObjectResolver.createApp= ...>
  <iisApp path="Default Web Site/Catalog" ...>
  ...
</MSDeploy.IisApp />
```

So IIS is exporting MSDeploy.IisApp while MSBuild is creating a sitemanifest.

How do I get MSBuild to match the IIS Export?  I'm using the VSTS build system and the parameters I'm passing to MSBuild are:

```
MSBuild /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\Catalog" /p:IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination=False
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue.

The specific issue I had been experiencing was a line in the logs that looked like this:

```
Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/1' could not be applied anywhere.
```

Parameters.xml was this (broken):

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="IIS Web Application Name"
         description="Full site path where you want to install the Catalog Application (for example, Default Web Site/Catalog)."
         defaultValue="Default Web Site/Catalog"
         tags="IisApp">
  <parameterEntry kind="ProviderPath" scope="iisApp" match="@defaultValue" />
</parameter>
```

I set the match attribute to an empty string. Then everything started working as expected.  Working:

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="IIS Web Application Name"
         description="Full site path where you want to install the Catalog Application (for example, Default Web Site/Catalog)."
         defaultValue="Default Web Site/Catalog"
         tags="IisApp">
  <parameterEntry kind="ProviderPath" scope="iisApp" match="" />
</parameter>
```